# ReactJS+FireStore Data mapping issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im writing a small program to fetch the categories from the Firestore DB and show in webpage as a list.

My code look like this:

```
class Category extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {'Categories': []}
  }
  render() {
    let categoryList = null;
    if (Array.isArray(this.state.Categories)) {
      console.log(this.state.Categories);
      categoryList = this.state.Categories.map((category) =>  {
        return <li>{category.name}</li>
      });
    }
    return(
      <ul>{categoryList}</ul>
    );
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    // fetch the data from the Google FireStore for the Category Collection
    var CategoryCollection = fire.collection('Category');
    let categories = [];
    CategoryCollection.get().then((snapshot)=> {
      snapshot.forEach ((doc) => {
        categories.push(doc.data());
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error in getting the data") 
    });
    this.setState({'Categories': categories});
  }
}
```

Im able to fetch the data and even populate this.state.Categories, however the map function is not getting executed.

The console.log statement produce an array of values butthe map function in render is not getting executed. Any thoughts?

Console.log output:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Your code works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/9j27k0zrxp (sorry but I've cleaned it up a bit). Also I would recomment to fetch data in a HOC or render-props component and leave this one for presentation purposes for separation of cencerns

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in handling data retrieval. In the last line categories is still empty, so it triggers setState with an empty data set. Should be something lie that

```
componentWillMount() {

    fire.collection('Category').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            const categories = snapshot.map(doc => doc.data());
            // sorry, but js object should be pascal cased almost always
            this.setState({ categories }); 
         })
         .catch(error => {
             console.log("Error in getting the data") 
         });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only return the data if the data exists. The simplest way to do this is to replace `<ul>{categoryList}</ul>` with `<ul>{this.state.categories && categoryList}</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work with a small change (moved this.setState to be inside the callback). Honestly, I still don't understand the difference.

P.S: I come from PHP development and this is my first step into ReactJS.

```
componentWillMount() {

    // fetch the data from the Google FireStore for the Category Collection
    var categoryCollection = fire.collection('Category');
    let categories = [];
    categoryCollection.get().then((snapshot)=> {
        snapshot.forEach ((doc) => {
            categories.push(doc.data());
        }); 
        if (categories.length > 0) {
            this.setState({'Categories': categories});
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
       console.log("Error in getting the data"); 
    });
    // this.setState({'Categories': categories});

}
```